# Message transforms for the MirrorMaker 2.0

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, apache-kafka-mirrormaker

I am running a dedicated MirrorMaker cluster and want to perform my SMT transformation for the records. Could you advice where should I put the jar with my code, i. e. where should I define `plugin.path` property?

Answer (score 0):

> where should I define plugin.path property?

The worker property file when you start either `connect-mirror-maker` or `connect-distributed`

> where should I put the jar

You need to make a subfolder under a directory listed in `plugin.path`, then put JARs there.